# Define rounding parameters for a planar point pattern in UTM

Tags: r, gps, digits, spatstat

I am analyzing a planar point pattern that was recorded using high resolution GPS equipment that is accurate to ~1 cm. My data frame consists of UTM coordinates (metres) to two decimal places, which I then convert to a ppp object using a study area polygon that is also in UTM.

Everything is importing and plotting as expected and I can run whatever `spatstat` functions on the ppp object I am after. However, when converting data frame to a ppp object, the coordinates are being rounded to the nearest 0.1 m.

Is there a way to define/control the number of decimal places when creating the ppp object? I want to preserve the significant digits down to 0.01 m for my analyses of correlation and spacing.

```
dat <- ppp(df[,1],df[,2], window = poly_owin)
summary(dat)
Planar point pattern:  1755 points

*Pattern contains duplicated points*

Coordinates are given to 1 decimal place
i.e. rounded to the nearest multiple of 0.1 m
```

I checked within both `df` and `dat` and the coordinates are not truncated at 0.1 m - the data still exists at the 0.01 m level. Yet, a Fry plot of `dat` shows regular spacing at 10 cm increments so the points are being discretized at 0.1 m for analysis.

Any help is very much appreciated.

**EDIT** (expanded dataset from previous example):

```
head(df)
      POINT_X     POINT_Y
1 337974.8571 6458115.131
2 337985.2904 6458132.547
3 337985.5247 6458131.010
4 337989.2619 6458130.392
5 337989.0793 6458128.664
6 337988.8296 6458127.859
head(coords(dat))
            x           y
1 337974.8571 6458115.131
2 337985.2904 6458132.547
3 337985.5247 6458131.010
4 337989.2619 6458130.392
5 337989.0793 6458128.664
6 337988.8296 6458127.859
summary(dat)
Planar point pattern:  6755 points
Average intensity 0.359048833914 points per square m

*Pattern contains duplicated points*

Coordinates are given to 1 decimal place
i.e. rounded to the nearest multiple of 0.1 m

Window: polygonal boundary
single connected closed polygon with 122 vertices
enclosing rectangle: [337968.2137, 338168.078494] x [6458047.265, 
6458200.4235] m
Window area = 18813.6 square m
Unit of length: 1 m
Fraction of frame area: 0.615
```

**EDIT 2**

```
head(coords(frypoints(dat)))
        x             y
1 10.4333 17.4160000002
2 10.6676 15.8789999997
3 14.4048 15.2609999999
4 14.2222 13.5329999998
5 13.9725 12.7280000001
6 10.7175 12.7379999999

fryplot(dat, width = 0.3)
```

[Fry plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgh0e.png)

Comment: Are the UTM coordinates the original data or have they been converted from lat,lon? Maybe the conversion causes the discretisation? At least there is nothing in `spatstat` that should cause this.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds strange. In `spatstat` no rounding is done -- the summary
method just detects whether the coordinates seem to be given to some
number of decimal places and then signals this.

```r
library(spatstat)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(4, 0, 10), y = runif(4, 0, 10))
dat <- ppp(df[,1], df[,2], window = square(10))
coords(dat)
#>           x        y
#> 1 0.2025274 3.458709
#> 2 9.2649444 2.272643
#> 3 5.3580148 1.270116
#> 4 8.4807510 7.745455
summary(dat)
#> Planar point pattern:  4 points
#> Average intensity 0.04 points per square unit
#> 
#> Coordinates are given to 7 decimal places
#> 
#> Window: rectangle = [0, 10] x [0, 10] units
#> Window area = 100 square units

df2 <- round(df, 2)
dat2 <- ppp(df2[,1], df2[,2], window = square(10))
coords(dat2)
#>      x    y
#> 1 0.20 3.46
#> 2 9.26 2.27
#> 3 5.36 1.27
#> 4 8.48 7.75
summary(dat2)
#> Planar point pattern:  4 points
#> Average intensity 0.04 points per square unit
#> 
#> Coordinates are given to 2 decimal places
#> i.e. rounded to the nearest multiple of 0.01 units
#> 
#> Window: rectangle = [0, 10] x [0, 10] units
#> Window area = 100 square units
```

Could you please try to add the output of the following to your
question?

```r
head(df)
head(coords(dat))
```

**EDIT:** Currently `spatstat` uses `all.equal` to guess the rounding of the data. However this only works for something like 8 significant digits, so when your coordinate values are large it is fooled. This does *NOT* mean that the coordinates are actually truncated -- it is just the guessing mechanism that is fooled. The input data is copied verbatim. How do you observe that "a Fry plot of `dat` shows regular spacing at 10 cm increments"? Could you please report the output of `head(coords(frypoints(dat)))`?

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. I've added the output you requested into my original question.

Comment: I should also add that the UTM coordinates are in metres and contain many more than the 3 or 4 decimal places shown in the output (although those past the millimetre are not significant). From whay I can discern, the number of digits displayed in the output is controlled by the digits setting.

Comment: Thanks again. Additional info provided as a second edit. Appreciate the explanation and the time.

Answer (score 0):

`spatstat` does not round the coordinate data. The function `ppp` copies the input data directly into the point pattern object without changing the data.

The printout from `print.ppp` mentions rounding because it is trying to *guess* the level of precision in the data. The guessing is performed by the `spatstat` function `rounding`, which basically checks whether `round(x, k)` is identical to `x` for a given number of digits `k`.

So my interpretation is that your spatial coordinate data, despite being recorded to a higher precision, are in effect discretised to the nearest 0.1 m. Although `rounding.ppp` can get it wrong sometimes because of numerical glitches, your description of the Fry plot supports the same interpretation.